# how to set up a fast and light development environment using docker?

Tags: docker

i have tried to learn some case like following:

1. https://github.com/ubermuda/docker-symfony
2. https://github.com/stage1/docker-php

but that above is not great for me. I need some post to tell me the complete process how to use docker with development.I have not problem with docker command such as docker-compose. Who have used docker as development environment? Give me some advice ,please.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I've written a tool that lets you set up a development environment inside docker. See http://dockershell.io/

Comment: it have no more features.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What feature are you referring to?

Comment: just like compose ,it can compose a variety of container. I could select some to compose from many  image of repository.

Comment: I use shell scripting for that purpose. The scripts themselves are about the same length as compose configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is MUCH too broad for it to be answerable in one reply.

I would start at the official Docker website, evaluate which images you might need (you can always build them yourself as well), and start putting your development environment together.

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Comment: I just want to know some a set of tools and experience  using docker as development environment. and Who have done it ?